# Levelplot(RasterVis) two marginal plot scale?

Tags: raster, r, profile

[image]

How can I add/display scale to two marginal plot?

```
RAD1998.all <- stack(list.ras)

list.files <- mixedsort(list.files(paste(getwd(), "/1998bil/", sep = ""), full.names = F, pattern = ".asc.bil")) 
#list.files

outlist <- substr(list.files, 31, 43)
#outlist

png(paste("1998",outlist[[1]],".png",sep=""))
levelplot(RAD1998.all[[1]])
dev.off()
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that this question is better asked here rather than at Stack Overflow (http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/guidance-on-geographically-related-questions-belonging-on-so-vs-gis-se) but if you think GIS SE, can you edit your question to provide some details about how you think this relates to GIS, please? Disclaimer: I do not work with R.

Comment: It could be a non GIS question but I am looking for a solution from RasterVis and two marginal plot gives lots of raster information. I wish if scale is added either or both sides then it will be easy to quantify raster data. All I want is that is there anyway I can add scale ?

Comment: More efficient to [directly ask](https://github.com/oscarperpinan/rastervis) the author

Comment: That's good idea.

Comment: It is not yet implemented. I will try to find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have [committed changes](https://github.com/oscarperpinan/rastervis/commit/e216e4b43163c189326f283ffbaf7278db3ec037) in the repository that implement the axis.

Use this code to install the latest development version:

```
## install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("rastervis", "oscarperpinan")
```

Then, use the new argument `axis.margin` to enable the axis.

```
 f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
 r <- raster(f)
 levelplot(r, axis.margin = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: My raster data is a NEXRAD rainfall data in inches per 5 min. Most of my raster cell values are less than 0.1"/5 min.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot. It worked beautifully. I don't know how attach an image file at a "Add Comment". axis.margin worked fine with overlaying shape files demonstrated in your github, oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/FAQ.html#sec-7. It's so beautiful. Thanks, Nahm